# Can I fly in the USA with an FAA ATP, if I don't have a commercial certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations

I am Taiwanese and I have an FAA ATPL, but I don't have an FAA CPL.

Can I fly commercial operations in the US?

Comment: I'm curious, how did you obtain an FAA ATP?

Comment: @digitgopher you can apply for the FAA ATP with a foreign commercial certificate with instrument privileges.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe. Your ATP certificate does give you commercial privileges, as per [14 CFR 61.167](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1167):

> (a) *Privileges*. (1) A person who holds an airline transport pilot
>   certificate is entitled to the same privileges as a person who holds a
>   commercial pilot certificate with an instrument rating.

But, that doesn't authorize you to work in the USA or even to enter the USA, which is an entirely different question about immigration law. As a foreigner, you'll need an appropriate visa or a green card in order to be legally employed and paid. You can ask more about that on [another site](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  If you have an ATP in the US it comes with all the privileges of a commercial license including flying for a 121 / 135 operator.

See [61.167](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=8f2d411d76869d0aa65b96fa7fa5aa50&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1167&rgn=div8):

> (a) *Privileges*. (1) A person who holds an airline transport pilot
>   certificate is entitled to the same privileges as a person who holds a
>   commercial pilot certificate with an instrument rating.